# How to get rid of following warning/error: Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_color_parse: assertion 'spec != NULL' failed

Tags: c, pango

I keep getting the following message with some of my applications:

Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_color_parse: assertion 'spec != NULL' failed

I am using this in Fedora 22. Can I track down the source of the error. FWIW, the application "works" fine, with the exception of rendering the transparency.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Doesn't the assertion point you to a specific line of code?

Comment: You should not pass a _null pointer_ for `spec` to `pango_color_parse` apparently. Without any further information: I suspect you did not verify the result of a function returning whatever you pass for `spec`.

Comment: No, it does not. Here is the error:

Comment: (aNu:5755): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_color_parse: assertion 'spec != NULL' failed

Comment: That 5755 is the process id, not the line number. Thanks again!